# Call spring boot tomcat from react native on android emulator doesn't work

Tags: spring-boot, react-native

I try to call this : http://localhost:8080/users/1

from react native code :

```
import base64 from "base-64";

const rootEndpoint = "http://localhost:8080/users/1";


const headers = {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  Accept: "application/json",
};

export const getRandomBrewdog = () => 
fetch(`${rootEndpoint}`, {headers}).then(
(response) => {
  if (response.status !== 200)
    throw new Error(`API answered with status code ${status}`); // gestion    du status code HTTP
  else return response.json(); // on parse la réponse en JSON
}
).then(function(response) {
return response;
```

})

Test with Advanced Rest Client under Chrome
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3ium.jpg)

Tomcat works, and the request is ok.

But it doesn't work with the fetch method...
Error : Network request failed (fetch.js:441:29)

index.js ---> calling getRandomBrewdog

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { AppRegistry, 
StyleSheet, 
ActivityIndicator, // import des composants
TouchableOpacity,
Text, 
View 
} from "react-native";

import { getRandomBrewdog } from './app'

class App extends Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props)

// la state de notre composant est utilisé pour
// stocker quelques infos renvoyées par l'API
this.state = {
name: '', // nom de la bière
description: '', // sa description
isLoading: false // la requête API est-elle en cours ?
}
}

// nous externalisons cette fonction afin de
// pouvoir l'appeler lorsqu'on le souhaite
_getRandomBrewdogWithFeedback = () => {
this.setState({ isLoading: true })

 getRandomBrewdog()
 .then(json => this.setState({
 name: json.name,
 description: json.description,
 isLoading: false // la requête est terminée
  }))
  .catch(error => console.error(error))
  }

 componentWillMount() {
 this._getRandomBrewdogWithFeedback()
 }


render() {
const content = this.state.isLoading
? <ActivityIndicator /> // si requête en cours, on affiche un spinner
: <View style={styles.infosContainer}>
  <Text style={styles.name}>
    {this.state.name} // sinon on affiche le nom de la bière
  </Text>

  <Text style={styles.description}>
    {this.state.description} // sa description
  </Text>

  <TouchableOpacity // on ajoute un "bouton" qui requête une autre bière    aléatoire
    onPress={this._getRandomBrewdogWithFeedback}
    style={styles.button}
  >
    <Text>Grab a new beer!</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</View>

return (
<View style={styles.container}>
{content}
</View>
)
}


}

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
 flex: 1,
 justifyContent: 'center',
 alignItems: 'center',
 backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
 },
 // ajout de styles divers
 infosContainer: {
 margin: 30,
 },
 name: {
 fontSize: 18,
 fontWeight: '700',
 marginBottom: 10,
 },
 description: {
 marginBottom: 10,
 },
 button: {
 borderWidth: 1,
 borderColor: '#000',
 borderRadius: 3,
 padding: 5,
 justifyContent: 'center',
 alignItems: 'center',
 }
 })
```

Comment: (1) Could you provide more information about the error? (2) Where are you calling your getRandomBrewdog() function from? (3) Try using https?

Comment: You're using port `8081` in your rest client screenshot, but your Javascript code is using port `8080`.

Comment: Yes, i have tested by changing the server.port, that's because there is 8081 in the screenshot

Comment: I have tried https. -> https://login:password@127.0.0.1:8080

Comment: i put the code calling getRandomBrewdog, index.js in the Question ->

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, i need to put the IP adress like this:
http://192.168.1.4:8080/users/1
It doesn't work with localhost or 127.0.0.1

And more, here the code is ok with token authentification :

```
import base64 from "base-64";

const rootEndpoint = "http://192.168.1.4:8080/users/1";

const name = "toto";
const password = "toto";
const authBase64 = base64.encode(`${name}:${password}`);

const headers = {
"Content-Type": "application/json",  
Accept: "application/json", 
Authorization: `Basic ${authBase64}` // HTTP basic auth
 };

export const getRandomBrewdog = () => 
fetch(`${rootEndpoint}`, {headers}).then(
  (response) => {
    if (response.status !== 200)
      throw new Error(`API answered with status code ` + response.status);
    else return response.json(); // on parse la réponse en JSON
  }
).then(function(response) {
  return response;
})
```